# Vector of the occurence number

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector `a=[1 2 3 1 4 2 5]'`

I am trying to create a new vector that would give for each row, the occurence number of the element in a. For instance, with this matrix, the result would be `[1 1 1 2 1 2 1]'`: The fourth element is 2 because this is the first time that 1 is repeated.

The only way I can see to achieve that is by creating a zero vector whose number of rows would be the number of unique elements (here: `c = [0 0 0 0 0]` because I have 5 elements).
I also create a zero vector d of the same length as a. Then, going through the vector a, adding one to the row of c whose element we read and the corresponding number of c to the current row of d.

Can anyone think about something better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a nice way of doing it

```
C=sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq,a,a.')))
```

My first suggestion was this, a not very nice `for` loop

```
for i=1:length(a)
    F(i)=sum(a(1:i)==a(i));
end
```

Comment: This is a for loop indeed but this is nice and much simpler than what I do!

Comment: I added a different method which might be more efficient.

Comment: +1 for using `triu`. Very clever! You could even turn it into a one-liner if you skipped B.

Comment: @nispio Good idea, nothing like a one-liner! I will edit my answer!

Comment: +1 Very nice. Just a quibble: you are taking the complex conjugate of  `a` (with `'`)

Comment: @Luis That's true! I haven't seen that before! Thanks. So as I understand it, using `'` gives the complex conjugate transpose, and `.'` is a "normal" transpose then. I will update my answer.

Comment: Caution with this solution - if a is big you will get "??? Error using ==> bsxfun. Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options."

Comment: @chappjc _Everybody_ ignores that detail. It has become a kind of pet peeve for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

This does what you want, without loops:

```
m = max(a);
aux = cumsum([ ones(1,m); bsxfun(@eq, a(:), 1:m) ]);
aux = (aux-1).*diff([ ones(1,m); aux ]);
result = sum(aux(2:end,:).');
```

Answer (score 4):

My first thought:

```
M = cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,a,1:numel(a)));
v = M(sub2ind(size(M),1:numel(a),a'))
```

Answer (score 4):

on a completely different level, you can look into [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) to get info about the frequency of the values. For example:

```
tabulate([1 2 4 4 3 4])

  Value  Count  Percent
  1      1      16.67%
  2      1      16.67%
  3      1      16.67%
  4      3      50.00%
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `tabulate`.  I would give +1 if this answered the question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the solutions proposed by David, chappjc and Luis Mendo are beautiful but cannot be used if the vector is big. In this case a couple of naïve approaches are:

```
% Big vector
a = randi(1e4, [1e5, 1]);
a1 = a;
a2 = a;

% Super-naive solution
tic
x = sort(a);
x = x([find(diff(x)); end]);
for hh = 1:size(x, 1)
  inds = (a == x(hh));
  a1(inds) = 1:sum(inds);
end
toc

% Other naive solution
tic
x = sort(a);
y(:, 1) = x([find(diff(x)); end]);
y(:, 2) = histc(x, y(:, 1));
for hh = 1:size(y, 1)
  a2(a == y(hh, 1)) = 1:y(hh, 2);
end
toc

% The two solutions are of course equivalent:
all(a1(:) == a2(:))
```

Actually, now the question is: can we avoid the last loop? Maybe using arrayfun?