# Speeding up Finding the Cumulative Occurrence of Elements

Tags: performance, matlab, find-occurrences

I'm trying to improve the performance of my code. The code basicly calculates the value of `L_total` (1x2640) and it does it by fetching the data from another variable called `L_CN` (1320x6). I also have `colindexes` matrix (2640x3) which stores the values of rows to look at in `L_CN`.

So, how this goes is, the code looks at `colindexes` to get the row data. Say `colindexes` is of the following form:

```
55    65    75
68    75    85
...
```

The program will calculate `L_total(1)` using `L_CN(55,1) + L_CN(65,1) + L_CN(75,1)`. Here the first indices refer to the row numbers obtained from the `colindexes` matrix. The second indices represent the number of occurrences of these row numbers so far. Therefore, when we calculate `L_total(2)`, it will be `L_CN(68,1) + L_CN(75,2) + L_CN(85,1)`. Here `L_CN(75,2)` happened because `L_CN(75,1)` was used before.

To calculate the entire `L_total` matrix, the following code works well. It stores the number of occurrences for each index by incrementing the corresponding index in a variable called `list`(2640x1) and thus calculates `L_total`. It does so in 0.023715 seconds. (Note that `n` is 2640 below)

```
for i=1:n
     list(colindexes(i,:)) = list(colindexes(i,:)) + 1;
     L_total(i) = sum(diag(L_CN(colindexes(i,:),list(colindexes(i,:)))));
end
```

The problem is, I will be running this portion of the code over and over, maybe like a million times. It's a part of a big simulation. Hence, even a smallest portion of increase in the performance is what I am after for. First, I thought getting rid of the for loop would serve for this purpose and switched the code into the following - getting a little help from this topic: [Vector of the occurence number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695619/vector-of-the-occurence-number):

```
list_col = reshape(colindexes',1,[]);
occurrence = sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq,list_col,list_col.')));
list = reshape(occurrence,3,[])';
straight_index = colindexes + (list - 1)*k;
L_total = sum(L_CN(straight_index),2)';
```

This code also does the job for `list_col` (1x7920), `occurrence` (1x7920), `list` (2640x3) and `straight_index` (2640x3). However, contrary to my expectations, it takes 0.062168 seconds, about three times worse than the for loop implementation. 0.05217 seconds of this operation is due the second line, where the occurrence matrix is formed. With array sizes like mine, it is truly inefficient to find the occurrences like this way.

The question is, with or without the for loop, how can I increase the performance of this code? The vectorization method seems nice, if only I can figure out a way to calculate the occurrence matrix faster. As I said, this portion of code will be run a lot of times, and thus any percent of increase in performance is welcomed.

Thank you!

Further info:
`colindexes` represent a big matrix of size 1320x2640. Instead of storing this entire matrix, I only store the row locations of '1's in this matrix in `colindexes`. The rest is zero. So the `colindexes` I specified in the question means, there is a '1' in 1st col 55th row and 2nd col 85th row... So the min,max range is 1,1320. There are only 3 '1's in each column, so that's why its size is 2640x3. This is, of course, background information, for how it is formed. If that helps, the number of occurences for each value in `colindexes` is also the same, which is 6.

So, for a matrix `A = [1 0 0 1; 0 1 1 0]`, the `colindexes` is `[1; 2; 2; 1]`.

Comment: 2640x1. Let me edit the OP.

Comment: The `n` would be? Sorry if I missed that.

Comment: It's alright, it's a huge code and I'm posting a portion of it. I may have skippped specifying a variable or two. n is 2640, I'll edit that too.

Comment: Could you post typical values, and maybe min and max values of `L_CN`, `list` and `colindexes`?

Comment: `colindexes` represent a big matrix of size 1320x2640. Instead of storing this entire matrix, I only store the row locations of '1's in this matrix in `colindexes`. The rest is zero. So the `colindexes` I specified in the question means, there is a '1' in 1st col 55th row and 2nd col 85th row... So the min,max range is 1,1320. There are only 3 '1's in each column, so that's why its size is 2640x3. This is, of course, background information, for how it is formed. If that helps, the number of occurences for each value in `colindexes` is also the same, which is 6.

Comment: Could you run this inside that `for` loop - `std(diag(L_CN(colindexes(i,:),list(colindexes(i,:)))))` and tell us if you are getting any non-zero or any value that is not very small (of the order of E-16)?

Comment: Not right away, but after some iteration as L_CN keeps getting updated, bunch of NaN values appear if I replace sum with std. I don't see the point you're getting at with standard deviation though. Can you explain more?

Comment: You don't need to replace the the `sum` with `std`, just add this `std` calculation above or below the line where `L_total` is being calculated. I tried with some rand numbers and the `diag` values are all same, so I thought we can avoid summing up.

Comment: Oh I see. Well I get std values around 2.35 - 1.2 as well. So they're not that small.

Comment: As far as I can see, if you used an actual `sparse` matrix instead of your own implementation, it would be as simple as `sum(data, 1);`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know MATLAB had that implementation already. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still using the for loop, consider storing `colindexes(i,:)` in a variable. You're using it 4 times. It might save you time marginally.